# Borrar archivos de una carpeta con php despues de un tiempo programado

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo programar un momento especifico para borrar un file de una carpeta de windows con php?, es decir, que funciones puedo usar? Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas algún script que quede funcionando constantemente y revise la hora (`daemon`), o con el programador de trabajos del sistema operativo que estés usando (en tu caso de Windows es "Programador de Tareas", "Task Scheduler" en inglés).

Si lo que necesitas es asignar esa tarea al programador entonces el comando es:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN "CARPETADELATAREA\NOMBREDETAREA" /TR "C:\CARPETA\FUENTE\PROGRAMA-O-SCRIPT" /ST HH:MM
```

Para mandar ese comando desde PHP se puede usar:

- [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php)
- [`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php)
- [`system`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.system.php)

Saludos.